# HTACCESS - How to make RewriteCond that will "cut" URL address

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Lastly I started development API for my web application. I want to make mine API look like those "famous" APIs like Discord one - good looking and easy-to-use. This is my folder hierarchy:

```
root:
   api:
      api.php
      .htaccess
```

I'd like to make RewriteCond in .htaccess file that will make link like that:

```
https://example.com/api/user/1234/test
```

Into something like that:

```
https://example.com/api/api.php?input=user/1234/test
```

I am new into .htaccess, but I have read some docs, but

- I am asking wrong question to google
- There isn't anything that may help me with that.

Thanks for help in advantage.

**EDIT 1**

My current .htaccess file only contains links to ErrorDocuments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, make sure your `.htaccess` is being read by Apache. `AllowOverride all` should appear in the directory block of your virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /path/to/web/root>
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then, add these lines to your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(api/v2/)(.*)
RewriteRule .* %1api.php?input=%2
```

This introduction to `mod_rewrite` from the apache docs is very helpful: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex

You can play around with different rules here: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=853262c5-e0a5-5048-96bc-684aec5da2fb